# Position of button is wrong on Android

Tags: html, css

I'm using `position:relative; top: Xpx;` to position a button. In my PC, the position is correct, but in Chrome and Firefox Android its position is wrong. I have tried also with `transform: translate`, but it gives me the same position in Android. Below you have images and the code. Is there an easy solution for this?

PC image:

[image: PC image]

Android image:

[image: Android image]

```css
.ventana_producto_oro {
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px groove var(--c_oro_o);
  border-radius: 2%;
  width: 355px;
  height: 570px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.imagen_producto_oro {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.boton_oro {
  background-color: var(--c_oro);
  height: 21px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  border: 3px groove var(--c_oro_o);
  border-radius: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.boton_oro:hover {
  background-color: var(--c_oro_c);
}

.boton_oro:link {
  color: black;
}

.boton_oro:visited {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="ventana_producto_oro">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">
        Alicates multifunción Leatherman Super Tool 300
    </h3>
    <img style="width: auto; height: 240px;" class="imagen_producto_oro" alt="Alicates multifunción Leatherman Super Tool 300" src="imagenes/alicates_leatherman_SP300.jpg">
    <br>
    <p>
        <b>Material:</b> acero inoxidable 420HC   <br>
        <b>Tamaño:</b> 21 x 6 x 2 cm<br>
        <b>Peso:</b> 273 gr<br>
        <br>
            Description...
     </p>
     <a style="position: relative; top: 34px;" class="boton_oro" target="_BLANK" href="https://amzn.to/3QV3AuL">129€</a>
</div>
```

Comment: In the images is the 129€ product. The button is displaced outside the golden box.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```css
.ventana_producto_oro{
  position: relative;
}
.boton_oro {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Remove

```css
.boton_oro {
    margin-right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This simplifies adding more products, and solves the problem in chrome android, but in firefox android some prices are now on top of the description text.

Comment: You need to format your code, what I answered will place the `.boton_oro` bottom of the `.ventana_producto_oro` div